# Is there a better method for InDesign -> Word?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, export, microsoft-word

I use InDesign for layout of pieces which range from 2 to 72+ pages.

On occasion I'll get a client request to send a PDF and Word file for the latest iteration of a piece so that someone somewhere can review the copy and edit it as necessary (Often legal reviews). The **goal** is an *easily* edited Word file which has identical text when compared to the original InDesign file.

I *know* there's no direct path from InDesign to Word. I'm aware of 2 methods for this conversion....

---

#### Method 1:

**Export InDesign to PDF, open PDF in Acrobat, save as Microsoft Word
file from Acrobat.**

- This is typically pretty **horrible** at maintaining any sort of edit-ability. Contents can and will drop out at times or be split into non-editable "woven" sections of text based upon InDesign elements. This method, more often than not, creates a mess which can take hours to actually clean up to a logical usable form for editing.
- I am aware of some online PDF to Word converters. These typically do a *much better* job of maintaining the PDF **appearance** in the resulting Word file. *However,* they tend to increase the complexity of things in Word in an effort to maintain layout - increasing the occurrences of "woven" elements in Word, where a line can't be edited without trowing off things everywhere else - making for **much** *more difficult* editing in Word. *That's not my goal.*

#### Method 2:

**Simply select and copy in InDesign, Paste into an open Word
document.** I then select all and reset the font to Calibri, and color to black, and on rare occasions, unify the types sizes.

- In general, this method works well - while being more manual in nature. The fewer text frames in InDesign the easier this method becomes. But even if text is split into multiple frames, it's merely a matter of manually copying text in a frame, pasting, copy next fame paste, etc. In general, this method doesn't account for graphics. Yes, I could copy/paste graphics into Word as well. But that's just an unwarranted headache presenting more problems than its worth. (Most often things are fine without any graphics - it's text which needs to be examined.)

---

I'm wondering... **Does anyone have a better method to move all text from an InDesign file to a Word file?** Copy/pasting can take quite some time if there are a lot of small text frames in InDesign — which are logical to have at times due to layout (I do always try and keep the amount of text frames to a bare minimum.)

My **ideal solution** would be a solid text (or Word) file which contains all the text present in an InDesign file and *possibly* maintains type sizes (so hierarchy is seen.) I'm not concerned with maintaining colors, fonts, indents, graphics, etc.

Searching online pretty much leads to "tutorials" for method #1 above - with or without using online converters.

Comment: Your method 2 is easily automated via os scripting facilities but i have no idea how to do it on a mac. You could do this with jsx too if you only knew in which sequence the frames need to be read.

Comment: @joojaa scripting isn't really a strong point for me - but I'l look into it. Frames merely need to be read in the order they appear in the INDD file... p1, p2, p3, etc. Most often the document has a couple frames on p1, then starting on p2 1 frame for the rest of the document. Any subsequent frames would be callouts or associated with graphics. Even IF frames were read slightly out of order, fixing that in a text or Word file is minimal.

Comment: Have you tried xml export of indesign? Might be easier who knows.

Comment: Yeah.. xml/html export, of course, can be done. And I can se BBEdit to translate HTML to text, but ultimately it creates quite the mess because it's still trying to maintain layout to a degree, even when everything is stripped from the export options.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is the best way but here it is... I use Articles panel for this. I put everything I need to be exported in articles. It is very easy to define order of items. After that I export to html. Then use Microsoft Word to open html.

Comment: This *does* work, but unfortunately adding each frame as an article isn't *really* any faster than merely copy/pasting into Word or a text file. But, this does allow one to control the order of frames in the export a bit more. It's merely not *more* efficient. It's more along the lines of equivalent.